# Exclude a php include file if filename matches

Tags: php

I have a list of includes in a `html/php` file named **aaa-project.php** being called by a single include named **related-portfolio-items.php**:

```
<?php include("inc/related-portfolio-aaa.php"); ?>
<?php include("inc/related-portfolio-bbb.php"); ?>
<?php include("inc/related-portfolio-ccc.php"); ?>
<?php include("inc/related-portfolio-bbb.php"); ?>
```

If this set of includes appears in the **aaa-project.php** file I need to exclude the first include **"related-portfolio-aaa.php**".

And replicate this in the **bbb-project.php** to exclude the "**related-portfolio-bbb.php**" include and so forth for the next includes.
Basically not have the related portfolio appear on the webpage that features that project.

So give each include an Id and set an `if` at the top of each project page where I state which "**related-protfolio-foo.php** to be excluded from showing or loading.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code into a new file. Call it `dependencies.php`, or something. Change the array at the beginning to include each of you include files. Then, on each page that you want to include your files, instead of including that whole stack of files, just include this one file, `include "dependencies.php";`, which will only include the files that don't match.

```
// Turn your junk into an array
$includes = array(
    "inc/related-portfolio-aaa.php",
    "inc/related-portfolio-bbb.php",
    "inc/related-portfolio-ccc.php",
    "inc/related-portfolio-bbb.php"
);

// Loop that shit
foreach($includes as $inc){
    $include = true;
    // Check if the current filename is in the format you mentioned
    if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "-project.php") !== false){
        // Get the prefix of the current filename
        $prefix = explode("-", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])[0];
        // Get the suffix of the include
        $suffix = explode(".", explode("-", $inc)[2])[0];
        // Check if it matches
        if($prefix === $suffix) $include = false;
    }
    if($include) include $inc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for speedy creation indeed.
Am too green to make this work. And, probably did not explain what I need properly.

Comment: At the top of each project page I want to set which "related-portfolio-foo.php include to not load.

Comment: Yes, that is what my answer does. Instead of including a list of files, add your files list to the array, and use this block of code to include your files instead of the stack of include calls.

Comment: @Ottoinoz - check the edit. I explained it a little better.

Comment: We might be tantalizingly close. Expanded instructions are great re creation of dependencies.php file. How would this code know appearing in aaa-project.php to exclude <?php include("inc/related-portfolio-aaa.php"); ?> ?

Comment: it would look like this: `<?php include("dependencies.php"); ?>` ... dependencies.php will include all the other files.

Comment: or `<?php include("inc/dependencies.php"); ?>`, depending on where you put the file.

Comment: Not working, sadly. Would I not need to have the above code being included in the dependencies.php file wrapped in php open and close tags? I tried both ways.

Comment: As said I tried one version with wrapping in vain. I also get two syntax errors in line "$prefix" and "$suffix" Thanks for all your help. I'll abandon what I thought would be rudimentary. Shall code this manually and pay the price in labour time.

Comment: i see. you must be using an older version of PHP then. that's why explode is giving u syntax errors. i'd correct it but i've already spent a lot of time on this and you say youre abandoning it anyway...

Comment: Thanks again. MAMP testing server running 5.6.7

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `basename()` to implement the logic.

Here are the references:

- [$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
- [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

Create a base template function like this,

```
function include_files($filename){
    $path_array = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
    $s = explode("-", $filename)[0];
    if (($key = array_search($s, $path_array)) !== false) {
        unset($path_array[$key]);
    }
    foreach($path_array as $str){
        include ("inc/related-portfolio-" . $str . ".php");
    }
}
```

And then in every **xxx-project.php** file, call the function like this,

```
include_files(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

**Edited:**

Let me illustrate this with an example. Instead of including `include_files()` function in every file, use a separate file that contains this function and include *that* file in all of your **xxx-project.php** files, like this:

**include.php**

```
function include_files($filename){
    $path_array = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
    $s = explode("-", $filename)[0];
    if (($key = array_search($s, $path_array)) !== false) {
        unset($path_array[$key]);
    }
    foreach($path_array as $str){
        include ("inc/related-portfolio-" . $str . ".php");
    }
}
```

And include this **include.php** file in all of your **xxx-project.php** files, like this:

**aaa-project.php**

```
<?php

    include("include.php");

    include_files(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

    // rest of your code
?>
```

**bbb-project.php**

```
<?php

    include("include.php");

    include_files(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

    // rest of your code
?>
```

and so on.

Comment: It seems I/we are getting closer. Could you expand on how to implement the above. And my array will keep growing over time to about 20 items. I obviously have to include both snippets into the each file, but how does the include_files stipulate which array  item to leave out on each respective page?

Comment: @Ottoinoz I've updated my answer. Please see the **edited** section of my answer.

Comment: We might have a problem if I call the code in the include.php straight into my webpage, it's not executing.

Comment: @Ottoinoz Well, then explicitely include `include_files(){ ... }` function in each of your **xxx-project.php** files.