# exclude function php

Tags: php

Would be great with an opposite "exclude" from include,

Comment: `if (somethig is true) { include }`

Comment: Because you don't need it. You just don't include it.

Comment: if you really really want to work this way, include the form in the `else` branch if your `if`.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: @Fille no - people have put effort in answering your question. Deleting your question would throw away their work as well.

Comment: Please stop defacing this post. We're not going to delete it, and you are not allowed to deface it. That's not how the site works.

Comment: Related: [how to exclude a file after including it in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24436563/2943403), [PHP How to exclude a file which is included in the file I am including?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62295281/2943403) , [Exclude a php include file if filename matches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34313057/2943403)  I also believe this question is rather unclear and poorly asked/presented (not a great fit for Stack Overflow and likely to confuse future researchers).

Answer (score 0):

You can't exclude, because the include happened before. The code is already executed at the time, you want to exclude it.

Best way to solve this issue is include conditionally:

```
if (!$loggedin) {
  include "loginForm.php";
}
```

Comment: i think you forgot a `!`, because currently you include the login form **only if** you are logged in

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, if you just copy & paste this code. You have to adapt it to your needs. I'm not your coding-assistant, I'm just trying to help

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you should do like this

1)Have some loginForm route like http://localhost:5000/login submit it for processing.

2) In that file set up the session and redirect to another route which will show you the newCartForm and logoutForm.

It is bad practice to show a form on the basis of one true or false condition.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
// Hide Navbar and Sidebar if User = Student
if ($_SESSION["role_user"] != "Student") {
  include "modulos/navbar.php";
  include "modulos/sidebar.php";
}
```

So in this case, for all users will be showing navbar and sidebar, except for "Student" role user.