# PHP How to exclude a file which is included in the file I am including?

Tags: php, include, require

Suppose I want to include `header.php` file and `header.php` already contains another file included `functions.php`. If in my `index.php` I am including `header.php` then naturally `functions.php` will also get included. But what if for some specific reason I want to break the joint and exclude `functions.php` while including `header.php`? Is this possible?

Comment: You can put a conditional around the `include`. Make it include by default and in cases you want it excluded set some varibale. `$dont_include` on those pages.

Comment: I know that... This kind of work around can be done... But I was hoping if PHP has a native method or a method that is more specific to this issue rather than me working around it (to maintain professionalism in code).

Comment: No.  You have to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since after a lot of searching I could not find a native PHP function the workaround I came up with is:

```
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != 'page-name.php'){ 
  include('functions.php'); 
}
```

With this code `functions.php` will be included in all pages from `header.php` except only on `page-name.php`

Answer (score -1):

You can just change for:

```
include_once 'functions.php';
```

so it only will include once even if Header.php and Index.php has it.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. You did not understand the question properly.